# SQL-Like to add rows to new table?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-like

I have two table that looks like this

[image]

[image]

I want the **CodeID** to be used as an `Like 'value%'`

Ex: 
`Like '1%' or Like '15%' or Like '11%'` whatever the value(in codeid) is for that particular mail

My final Table should look like this:

[image: enter code here]

I'm stuck on how i will achieve this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a `join`:

```
select t1.*, t2.codelongid
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on cast(t2.codelongid as varchar(255)) like cast(t1.code as varchar(255)) + '%';
```

The column names suggest that the values are numbers.  Although you an use numbers with `like`, this involves implicit conversion to character strings.  I prefer to be explicit.  Of course, if the columns are already strings, the `cast()`s are unnecessary.

Comment: This is perfect thank you.
I will mark your answer as correct :)

Comment: The only thing OP will need to note though is if I am not mistaken, they may end up with unexpected duplicates as like '15%' rows will be again included when joining on like '1%'

Comment: Hmm.. Im not exactly following?. Test1 should see everything that has to do with '1%' and that includes '15%' as well. But test2 should only see '15%'